# jq does not show null output

Tags: bash, terminal, sh, jq

I have the following code in the command line script:

```
output_json=$(jq -n \
                 --argjson ID "${id}" \
                 --arg Title "${title}" \
                 --argjson like "\"${like}\"" \
                '$ARGS.named')
```

I put the `id`, `title` and `like` variables into the `jq`. I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Title": "ABC",
    "like": ""
  },
  {
    "ID": 22,
    "Title": "ABC",
    "like": "Yes"
  }
]
```

But, I am trying to get the output in the following format, i.e. with null:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Title": "ABC",
    "like": null
  },
  {
    "ID": 22,
    "Title": "ABC",
    "like": "Yes"
  }
]
```

I don't quite get it is it possible to do this in general, or is it a problem with my `jq` command?

And as far as I understood `"like": ""` is not the same as `"like": null`. I am also a little confused now, and do not really understand what is the correct choice to use.

Comment: As per the [mcve] guidelines, it would be helpful if you could show the values of the shell variables of interest, i.p. `$like`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `--argjson` you need to provide valid JSON-encoded argument, thus if you want to receive `null` the value needs to be literally `null`. Your solution, however, adds quotes around it, so it can never be evaluated to `null`. (Also, it will only be a valid JSON string if it follows the JSON encoding for special characters such as the quote characters itself).

If you want to have a JSON string in the regular case, and `null` in the case where it is empty, import the content of `${like}` as string using `--arg` and without the extra quotes (just as you do with `${title}`), then use some `jq` logic to turn the empty string into `null`. An `if` statement would do, for example:

```sh
like=
jq -n --arg like "${like}" '{like: (if $like == "" then null else $like end)}'
```

```json
{
  "like": null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes more sense now. Is there any way to imply `'${like}'' '{like: (if $like == "" then null else $like end)}'` directly into my command?

If I do:

`
output_json=$(jq -n \
                 --argjson ID "${id}" \
                 --arg Title "${title}" \
                 --arg like "${like}" '{like: (if $like == "" then null else $like end)}' \
                '$ARGS.named')
`

get the following result:

`
[
  {
    "like": null
  },
  {
    "like": "Yes"
  }
]
`

Comment: @KarlsD You can only have one filter, so you need to integrate the `if` statement into your actual filter (given your example, I thought it was just a dummy filter, therefore I came up with another simple case). But if you actually want to build upon just `$ARGS.named`, then try `$ARGS.named | .like |= if . == "" then null else . end`.